# Why is the special form of space-time interval chosen out of the invariance of the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, symmetry, invariants

On [page 4 of Landau & Lifshitz's The Classical Theory of Fields](https://archive.org/details/LandauTheClassicalTheoryOfFields/page/n13/mode/2up), the interval$$ds^2=c^2dt^2-dx^2-dy^2-dz^2$$ is introduced after the invariance of the velocity of light is stated, and later, after the invariance of this interval is proved, the Lorentz transformation is derived.

Why is this special form of interval chosen out of the invariance of the speed of light?

Comment: Going from invariance -> interval -> transform seems "artificial" to me, but then I haven't seen the proof ;)  I can offer a derivation with invariance -> transform -> interval here: https://mathpages.com/rr/s1-07/1-07.htm  I _believe_ it answers your question (see discussion of "k" value).

Comment: By "artificial" I mean "back to front" (missed comment edit window, although link was still there!)

Answer (score 4):

The motivation given in the book is that a light signal propagating radially from a point source has $\Delta s=0$ in *all* frames.

Comment: Wow!  Is that _really_ a motivation, seems completely opaque to me (compared with derivation in my comment to the OP)?  Can you maybe outline how that assumption is used?

Comment: They use it to show that for any object, $ds_1$ is proportional to $ds_2$ (the index runs on different frames). They use this to show that $ds_1=ds_2$

Comment: OK thanks for replying, still don't get it, think I'll stick to the explanation above ;)